# Css/php - move block right

Tags: php, css, wordpress, move

I'm trying to move this box all over to the right side of screen, no matter the resolution, but I cant find the answer.

My code is this

```
wp_get_archives(
    array(
        'type' => 'postbypost',
        'limit' => 5,
        'format' => 'html',
        'before' => '<span style="display: block; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); width: 300px; position: relative; top: 30px; right: 0; padding: 20px 20px 13px 20px; font-size: 17px; text-align: right; list-style-type: none; ">',
        'after' => '</span>',
    )
);
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing to make it go to the right side of the screen, no matter the resolution used?

Thanks!

Comment: Plz add the html template of it as well

Comment: did you try align="right"?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `float:right;` in your code: [Link to W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

You have to think about using a css class for making your span better readable.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say what the constraints are here and I'm not too familiar with WP, but have you tried setting the following CSS?
     position: absolute;
     right:0;